# Composing two functions in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and I am having trouble defining a certain composition of functions.

Let `m1` and `m2` be maps such that `m1: R^2 -> R^2` and `m2:R^2->R^1` where R is the real line

```
m1[eta_, zeta_] = {eta^3, zeta^3} 
m2[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2

m3[eta_, zeta_]  = Composition[m2, m1][eta, zeta]
```

On evaluating the last line, i.e. `shift+enter`I get the output

```
m2[{eta^3, zeta^3}]
```

But the anwer to this should be `m3[eta,zeta]=eta^6 + zeta^6`

How can I do this?

Comment: This is the [second](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17541/52) [time](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17559/52) you've cross posted a question with minutes of each other. Please give people a chance to answer, first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `m1` returns a list containing 2 elements, whereas your function `m2` requires 2 arguments. Change either what `m1` returns or what `m2` expects.  In this case it might be easier to redefine `m2` as

```
m2[{x_, y_}] = x^2 + y^2
```

The clue is that `m2[{eta^3, zeta^3}]` is just the sort of output Mathematica gives when you provide the wrong sort of arguments to a function -- it returns the input expression unevaluated.  You'll see this a lot as you learn.

Oh, and you probably want to use `SetDelayed` (generally written as `:=`) rather than `Set` (or `=`) in your function definitions.  See the documentation for why you probably want this.

Answer (score 1):

Write: m3[eta_, zeta_] = m2@@m1[eta,zeta]